# Filtering array of JSON data using multiple controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

I've used bootstrap and jquery to make a nice little mobile app that pulls an array of objects from a URL and create a table of them.  Now I have about 5 controls (button groups and dropdowns) that I'd like to use to filter the JSON data.  My question is should I use ajax? I'd like to have the filter occur without a page refresh when any of the controls are changed.  It's been many years since I've used ajax (back when I developed in .NET) but I know it's built into jquery.  Here's my jquery function that builds my table of objects:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://json.url/";
    $.getJSON(url, 
        function ( json ) { 
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                //Create each table row
                tr = $('<tr data-id="' + json[i].id + '" class="tap">');
                tr.append("<td>" + "<span>" + json[i].part_number + "</span>" + "<br>" + 
                                    json[i].diameter + '\"  &raquo; ' + json[i].phases + ' &raquo; ' + 
                                    json[i].voltage + ' &raquo; ' + json[i].rpm);
                tr.append("</td></tr>");
                $('table').append(tr);
             }
    });
});
```

Would it be better to keep the original array and store it? Or maybe call it every time I click one of the filters?  I have 4 bootstrap button groups and and 3 select inputs that I want to use to filter when any or all of them are changed (preferably without a submit button). I'm reading up on jquery.ajax now but wanted to get a question out there because I'm sure I'll need a little assistance.

Answer (score 0):

How could AJAX help you? Does the JSON url allow you to provide params and it will filter the data for you?

If the url you are making the `getJSON` request does not filter data for you, I think you will have to store the data in an array in javascript, and perform filters on that array based on the values of the options you provide

Comment: I never thought of filtering the data at the json url level.  I figured AJAX would prevent the page refreshes (this will primarily be on mobile).

Comment: Would I filter the returned json data or the database with each call to the json url?